# InkScape: Convert all white colors to transparent

Tags: inkscape, fonts, vector, svg, font-design

I have a set of svg icons. Each icon is composed of two colors black and white. I want to convert these svgs to a ttf font file. So I want the fonts to be monochrome. For that I first need to convert all the white colors in the svg files to transparent. Is there an easy way to do this using Inkscape?

Please note I don't need to convert white background to transparent background. The background is already transparent. I just want to convert the white colors to transparent.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you select the white elements and just delete them? If not, maybe share one of the icons on svgshare.com so we can see how it's constructed.

Answer (score 3):

Inkscape has Edit > Select Same. Select one white item and then those which have the same stroke or fill color. Adjust the opacity to 0% or remove the color.

Unfortunately changing the opacity in fill&stroke dialog changes both stroke and fill opacity. You may need to remove the fill color if it's white and the stroke is say green or black. There's no automatic global "change all white to transparent and keep other colors intact"